# If ActiveMQ Artemis cluster is running in a Kubernetes environment, is the ON_DEMAND load-balancing required for a backup-node to operate?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, activemq-artemis

**Kubernetes Configurations**

- Kuberenetes StatefulSet(replicas=2) for the live-nodes:

  `live-node1` ( paired with `backup-node1` for HA )

  `live-node2` ( paired with `backup-node2` for HA )
- Kubernetes Service for the live-nodes:

  `live-node`
- Kuberenetes StatefulSet(replicas=2) for the backup-nodes:

  `backup-node1`

  `backup-node2`
- Kubernetes Service for the backup-nodes:

  `backup-node`

**Note**: Clients(Publisher/Consumer) always connect to the cluster via the K8s service - `live-node`

---

**Scenario**

- `client1` is connected to `live-node1`
- `live-node1` goes down
- `backup-node1` takes over
- `client1` will try to reconnect via the K8s service - `live-node`
- Either it connects back to `live-node1` ( if it is back up ) OR ends-up connecting to `live-node2`
- **How the existing-messages and new-messages will be consumed and published in the latter case ??**

**My Understanding**

- All clients of `live-node1` will connect to the `live-node2`
- The existing-messages will be redistributed to `live-node2` as no consumer on the `backup-node1`
- The new-messages will be sent-to and consumed-from the `live-node2`

Please elaborate on this behavior and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What kind of clients are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram I am using JMS(port 61616) and Stomp(port 61613) clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking the `message-load-balancing` type configured on your `cluster-connection` is completely unrelated to how backups works. The `message-load-balancing` type, as the name suggests, is related to how messages are load-balanced around a cluster. How the backup behaves is determined by the `ha-policy` you have configured.

The whole point of having a backup is that when the live node fails all the clients connected to the live node will fail-over to the backup node. Furthermore, the backup node will have all the same messages that the live node had (either via replication or shared storage). Therefore, your expectation that all the clients connected to `live-node1` will connect to `live-node2` when `live-node1` fails is misguided.

That said, *if* clients do actually connect to `live-node2` instead of `backup-node1` then the `message-load-balancing` type would need to be `ON_DEMAND` if you wanted messages to eventually be redistributed from the `backup-node1` to `live-node2`. Obviously the `redistribution-delay` would also need to be greater than 0.